# Am I correct in saying I can bound any continuous probability distribution's input and not miss much??

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am thinking that:
For any continuous distribution over $\mathbb R$, $\forall \epsilon$ we can define an lower and upper boundary $s_{min}$ and $s_{max}$ such that $Pr(x<s_{min})+Pr(x>s_{max}) \le \epsilon$.

This feels true, since the CDF is bounded above and below, and is monotonic.

Comment: This is true for any random variable/distribution (if $F$ is a CDF, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=0$).

Comment: Oh this is how a limit is defined, (duh).

Comment: "not miss much" will depend on what you want to do with this approximation